# python use the output of a class inside another class

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I have the structure of a code described below which is made of two classes. What I want to do is to use the returned value from  classname1 and all its methods inside the classname2. 
I would appreciate your help.

```
class   classname1(someObject):

      def __init__(self, someInput1):
           self.someInput = someInput

      def someMethod (self):
          'code '
          return something

class  classname2(someObject):

       def init(self, someInput2)
            self.someInput2 = someInput2

       def AnotherMethod(self):

       use the returned value from the first class
```

Comment: Hint: class names should start with a capital letter, method names with `_` or a small letter

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "the returned value from classname1"? If you do `a = classname1(some_arg)` an instance of the `classname1` class is created, and then initialized by calling its `__init__` method with the `some_arg` parameter. The resulting object will then be bound to the name `a`. If you want, you can create an instance of `classname1` in a method of `classname2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of returning the value to class-2, you can probably:
       create instance of class 2 in class 1 & pass return value as argument to function in class 2.

eg:

```
class   classname1(someObject):
      def __init__(self, someInput1):
           self.someInput = someInput
      def someMethod (self):
          'code '
          //here create instance/object of class 2 
          //pass the return value to another method of class 2  

class  classname2(someObject):
       def init(self, someInput2)
            self.someInput2 = someInput2
       def AnotherMethod(self):
        // here receive the return value (from class 1) as one of the arguments.
```

or you can do it vice-versa:

```
class   classname1(someObject):
      def __init__(self, someInput1):
           self.someInput = someInput
      def someMethod (self):
          'code '

class  classname2(someObject):
       def init(self, someInput2)
            self.someInput2 = someInput2
       def AnotherMethod(self):
        //here create instance/object of class 1 
        //val num=class1Object.someMethod()
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

To get all methods of `Classname1`, `Inherit` it by

```
class Classname2(Classname1):
```

**For example**

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, someInput1):
        self.someInput1 = someInput1

    def someMethod1(self):
        return "something1"       


class B(A):

    def __init__(self, someInput2):
        self.someInput2 = someInput2

    def someMethod2(self):
        return "something2"


temp1 = B("ccc")
print(temp.someMethod1())
print(temp1.someMethod2())

#output
something1
something2
```

To call method of `class A` in `class B`

```
class B(A):

    def __init__(self, someInput2):
        self.someInput2 = someInput2

    def someMethod2(self):
        return self.someMethod1() # someMethod1 is method of A which is inherited to B
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much. And how do I call the someMethod inside the AnotherMethod? Much appreciated